# How to do multiple line editing?

Tags: eclipse, line

I want to edit multiple lines in eclipse, but I can't find any short cut or Plugin. In Geany I just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> I can add / edit multiple lines.

Maybe this example can explain what I mean:

```
var text = "myname";
var addr = "myaddr";
var age = "myage";
```

I want to edit text above into:

```
var my_text = "myname";
var my_addr = "myaddr";
var my_age = "myage";
```

The text above is just a simple example, but sometimes I have many lines of words that I have to edit its prefix.

Comment: http://www.robertwloch.net/2011/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-block-selection-mode/

Comment: I personally open up another code editor `like VS Code` to do just this.

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya what do you mean ? An external app or an extension ?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to ***Toggle block selection*** (Toggle block / column selection in the current text editor), this will let you write vertically in eclipse, then you can easily do this.

---

Go to Window->Preferences.

[image]

Find for binding in text box surrounded by red box.

Comment: @yuda: Go to Window->Preferences. Then in General->Keys. Find for Toggle Block selection and change it's binding to some other key. Or Find for Alt + Shift + A and change/remove other bindings except toggle block selection.

Comment: how to filter or find other key's that binding to alt+shift+A..?

Comment: its purely depends on you and your typing speed. For help learn more eclipse shortcuts this will also increase your speed of work.

Comment: It's worth noting this works only when the edits you want to make are column-aligned.

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman I guess that's what multiline editing means. You can edit at multiple places in multiple line, it should always be in column.

Comment: @Harry Joy - In some editors, you can have multiple cursor points that aren't necessarily column aligned, on different lines, editing. Eclipse doesn't, near as I can tell, offer that option.

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman yes Eclipse doesn't provide this, other IDE might be providing this as I am not aware of that. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA provides multi collumn selection (ALT + J selects additional occurance of selected word)

Comment: After press "alt + shift + A to Toggle block selection" combination then press shift + down arrow for multiple column selection

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. 
Bind keys in mac will change cursor to (+) so, we can select string to multiple select with SHIFT + array, like we block string.

Comment: What if we want to write on multiple different lines?

Comment: and how disable that multiple cursor , by pressing what exactly ?

Comment: @Hamdy by pressing again the exact same combination. `Shift + Alt + A`

Answer (score 33):

On OS X, the key combination for multi-line edits in Eclipse (or STS) is <kbd>option/alt</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

The Eclipse 4.22 (Q4 2021) equivalent of Geany would <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the lines you want to edit in one go.

Eclipse now supports

> ### [Multiple text selection](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/platform.php#multi-selection)
>
> Support for multiple selection has been added to Text Editors.
>
> Multi selections allow most edit operations (text replacement or insertion, extend selection to next word or to next line, copy/paste...) to apply simultaneously on all ranges.
>
> [image: multi edit -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/images/multi-carets.png]
>
> Multiple strategies are available to enable multi-selections:
>
> - Turn a block selection into a multi-selection using the To multi-selection command,
> - Add a caret with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>,
> - Use the new `Select All` button on the `Find/Replace` dialog.

So check if this would work in your case.

---

[jotschi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644326/jotschi) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460945/how-to-do-multiple-line-editing/70319081#comment125426553_70319081)

> Is it also possible to turn a regular selection into a multi selection? (Similar to Ctrl+D in VSCode).
> I see that the "`To Multi Selection`" is triggered, but it does not create a multi-selection for other occurrences. Do I have a wrong expectation here?

[Manohar Bhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7293057/manohar-bhat) answer (still [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460945/how-to-do-multiple-line-editing/70319081#comment135376720_70319081)):

> You are first supposed to do block selection and then press "`To Multi Selection`" keybinding.
> It will then insert multiple cursors.
>
> But multi cursors are not that useful in Eclipse as in VSCode, because if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, it will not select the next word under all carets.
> Instead, multi carets will go away, and it will just select next word under last caret.
>
> More detail in in [`dbeaver/dbeaver` issue 6064](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6064#issuecomment-1019522289): "Add support for Multiple selections (multi-cursor)".

Related: "[How to do multiple line editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319081/6309)" (end of the answer)

Comment: Is it also possible to turn a regular selection into a multi selection? (Similar to Ctrl+D in VSCode). I see that the "To Multi Selection" is triggered but it does not create a multiselection for other occurrences. Do I have a wrong expectation here?

Comment: @Jotschi I don't think this is directly supported. From the issue, I only see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466532#c66 (and its following comment/answer)

Comment: @Jotschi you are first supposed to do block selection and then press "To Multi Selection" keybinding. It will then insert multiple cursors. But multi cursors is not that useful in eclipse as in VS Code because if you press ctrl+shift+right, it will not select next word under all carets. Instead multi carets will go away and it will just select next word under last caret. More details here: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6064#issuecomment-1019522289

Comment: @ManoharBhat Thank you (again). I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

The Eclipse 4.24 (June 15 2022) will integrate it (See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576377):

- Multi selection down relative to anchor selection (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-J)
- Multi selection up relative to anchor selection (e.g. Alt-J)
- End multi-selection (e.g. ESC)
- Add all matches to multi-selection (e.g. Ctrl-Shift-Alt-J)
- Multi caret up (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Up)
- Multi caret down (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Down)

Thanks to eclipse contributor !

Comment: I do have Eclipse 4.24 and I cannot do multi caret up or down. Can I have the confirmation that it is working ? Thanks

Comment: Multi selection down relative to anchor selection - this is exactly what Ctrl+D does in codium/vscode. In my long-time updated eclipse version I just didn't have the shortcuts set, but the feature is there! I added Ctrl+D binding for this and yet Esc binding for "End multi-selection" and it really works! Thanks to eclipse contributor!

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following plugin,

https://github.com/caspark/eclipse-multicursor/releases

With this multiple occurrence of same text can be selected and edited. This is similar to multi select functionality available in editors like Sublime and Visual studio code.

Comment: searching eclipse-multicursor on google brings me back here

Comment: The project is dead :(

Answer (score 1):

Press key - { Alt + Shift + A } You will see A [+] symbol in IDE then use this symbol as drag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I still want to share my way of multi select and editing. However this way is restricted to only the same variables across the file. Simply highlight the variable to edit, right click, choose Refactor->Rename. Then edit the variable and it will also edit the same variables across the file. Hope it helps..:)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To select a variable automatically then rename, use the following shortcut.

CTRL+ 2 R

Change  or modify the variable.

[image]

Fedora 38 Linux

Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)